# node.js mySQL sending an array with INSERT statement formatting

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

I have the following contents in an array which is was printed from:

```
    console.log([userData]) //From HTML Form 
-------------------------------
[ [ 'test3',
    'Alice',
    'Weather',
    'Bob',
    'Doe',
    'john.doe@gmail.com',
    'Footballer',
    'male',
    'english',
    'married',
    '1965-01-02' ] ]
```

Now i need that to be inserted in a mySQL database and the result was a syntax error.The thing which i do not seem to understand is how to format the array in way which mySQL can 'understand'

```
 var sql = "INSERT INTO users (uid,FirstName,LastName,MotherName,FatherName,Email,Profession,Gender,MaritalStatus,Birthday) VALUES ?";
con.query(sql, "'" + userData.join() + "'", function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("inserted")
});
```

**Output:**

> **Error**: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near
>   ''\'test3,Alice,Weather,Bob,Doe,john.doe@gmail.com,Footballer,male,english,married,1965-01-02'
>   at line 1

Thanks.

Comment: what is `english` in `userdata`? Do you have column for that in database. This is the issue. No of columns in table & no of values you're passing is not same.

Comment: @HarshilDoshi If that was the error, then that would be the error message.

Comment: @HarshilDoshi Great Catch! That is also one of the issue that i forgot to skim through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not join the userData, because once joined, it becomes a whole string and mysql library do the substitution into `?`. And the whole query breaks down like this:

`INSERT INTO users (uid,FirstName,LastName,MotherName,FatherName,Email,Profession,Gender,MaritalStatus,Birthday) VALUES "'test3,Alice,Weather,Bob,Doe,john.doe@gmail.com,Footballer,male,english,married,1965-01-02'"`

and that is definitely a wrong SQL.

To properly insert the values, you have to pass the value as-is to mysql library:

```js
con.query(sql, [[userData]], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("inserted")
});
```

The secondary parameter should be "triple array", i.e. [[['test3', 'alice'.... ]]].

Which the first array denotes you are passing a series parameters for mysql library to do subsitution, the second array encloses the value of the parameter (i.e. to be substituted to the `?`), the third array tells mysql library that this parameter is an array of values.